# How to track changes between a production version and its github repo at certain hash point

Tags: git, github, diff, head

We have the next situation:

1. A while ago we cloned a develop branch repo from GitHub to our live production server.
2. Then I started to made new commits to the dev branch at GitHub.
3. At the same time the other guy made changes to the repo clone at the live server by FTP.

What we need is:

1. Compare the modified repo on the remote server with its origin commit (by hash or whatever) to track the differences.
2. Manually apply such changes to my local dev branch head.
3. Commit everything to the GitHub repo.
4. Pull the fresh dev branch to our live server.

As you see the origin of the live server repo is not the head anymore. I'm curious is there a way to diff the live server repo with its origin commit?

Comment: Yes, why don't you use `git fetch` and `git diff`?

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, but is the git fetch supposed to fetch the head branch? Because I need to get the differences between the live server copy and its origin commit, which lags behind about 30 commits now.

Comment: I wish to rephrase it. Suppose the live server is my local machine. I cloned a develop branch (which head HASH is 5df1c52) to my local machine. And I made changes to it. The remote branch on GitHub was updated by the other guy. And I want to see the differences between my local branch copy and it is origin branch which is 5df1c52.

Comment: Run `git diff 5df1c52` from your local copy?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood the situation, either of the following will work:

- On the live server, run `git diff`. This will show all "uncommitted changes", that is files which are different locally from whatever was last checked out. Save this output to a file, and you can apply it somewhere else with `git patch`.
- On the live server, create a branch, commit to it, and push it up to Github, e.g. `git checkout -b live-changes; git commit -am 'Unchecked live changes'; git push` Then on your local copy, you can check that branch out, merge it, etc, just as if someone had contributed the changes from their own PC.

In both cases, it doesn't matter what someone else has done with any particular branch; the live server knows what commit it had checked out, and can compare or commit against that.

Comment: I solved the matter in a different way. Anyway I'll check your solution as soon as I have some time for it. If it is applicable, you'll get the green check for your answer)